# Why were these questions closed as duplicates?

Tags: support, specific-question, exact-duplicates

The question [Need Examples to Understand Choice Function and Choice Structure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1443429/need-examples-to-understand-choice-function-and-choice-structure) is in no way a duplicate for the following question:

[(P(X),CR) may be a choice structure even if R is not a rational relation In the former](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1443029/px-c-r-may-be-a-choice-structure-even-if-r-is-not-a-rational-relation)

I have asked people to provide me some examples to understand the definition of Choice function and Choice structure. In the other question, I have asked for an example to show that a relation underlying a choice structure should not necessarily be a rational relation. The only relation between these two questions is the definition included in the latter question to clarify the question. I though including the definitions will help people to understand my question! Would you please reopen my question or at least tell me how I can clarify the distinction between my question and request reopening them. Thank you.

Comment: @Lord_Farin, I modified the question based on your comment. Do you think it is better now? By the way, please feel free to modify it if you think it is required.

Comment: Yes, it looks much better now :). To convey your points more clearly you might want to split them up into separate paragraphs, but in the end this is a stylistic choice.

Comment: @Lord_Farin, Thank you again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These questions:

- [Need Examples to Understand Choice Function and Choice Structure.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1443429/understanding-a-choice-function)
- [If a choice structure satisfies WARP, then the underlying binary relation is rational.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1443728/if-a-choice-structure-satisfies-warp-then-the-underlying-binary-relation-is-rat)

were closed as a duplicates of this question: [$(P(X), C_R)$ may be a choice structure even if $R$ is not a rational relation.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1443029/px-c-r-may-be-a-choice-structure-even-if-r-is-not-a-rational-relation).

You authored all questions. Looking at this, it indeed look like they are duplicates. I am not expert in your field, but if you post very similar questions, you should at least explain how your new question is different.

So, if indeed, the two closed questions above different questions, then just edit them and reference your previous question. Explain how your new question isn't solved in answers to the old question and how it is different. After editing them the questions are automatically nominated for reopen. Enough people will then get to vote on whether or not to reopen.

You can also post a reopen request here:  http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19042/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-etc-volume-01-2015-current-versio

Comment: OK. From my point of view these questions are totally different and I can fully explain why. Would you please let me know how to request reopening these question to modify them and explain why they are different? By the way, I have asked a question here that I don't see any problem with it. Would you please tell me why people have given my questions down-votes?

Comment: @user2521204: After you edit the question, the question is put in a review que. Here other users will vote on whether or nor to reopen. You can also post a request in http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19042/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-etc-volume-01-2015-current-versio. But again, remember to explain clearly why your question is different.